# Proof of Goursat theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

*If $f : U \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is differentiable in $U$ open subset of $ \mathbb{C}$ then $f$ is analytic in $U$.*

(In the proof you consider a triangle $T_1$ in $U$, subdivide it in a sequence of smaller triangles $T_n $, observe that $ \displaystyle \bigcap_{n=1} ^{\infty} T_n = \lbrace z_0 \rbrace $, show that $ \displaystyle \int _{\partial T_1} f(z) dz = 0 $ and then apply Morera's theorem).

At a certain point in the proof, since $f$ is differentiable it is stated correctly that
$$ |f(z) - f(z_0) - f'(z_0)(z-z_0)| \leq \varepsilon_n (z-z_0)$$
with $\varepsilon_n \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$; then
$$ \left| \int_{\partial T_n} f(z) dz \right| = \left| \int_{\partial T_n} f(z) - f(z_0) - f'(z_0)(z-z_0) dz \right| $$
How is this obtained?

Comment: Hi, welcome to math.SE! The way to mark a question as solved is to [click the grey checkmark next to the answer](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/3287/856). Cheers.

Comment: @Alex The best way to indicate that the issue has been resolve is the accept the answer that solved it. If you worked it out by yourself, please consider taking a moment to sketch the solution by writing up your own answer. You can accept that answer then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\int_{\partial T_n} f(z) dz = \int_{\partial T_n} f(z_0) dz + \int_{\partial T_n} f'(z_0)(z-z_0) dz + \int_{\partial T_n} \left(f(z) - f(z_0) - f'(z_0)(z-z_0) \right) dz$$

Now the constant term $f(z_0)$ and the linear term $f'(z_0)(z-z_0)$ have primitives and hence you can integrate them out to get $0$.

Hence, $$\int_{\partial T_n} f(z) dz = \int_{\partial T_n} \left(f(z) - f(z_0) - f'(z_0)(z-z_0) \right) dz$$

Comment: Thank you. Forgot that $\partial T_n$ is a closed curve...

Comment: @Alex You do not need to write [solved] on the question title. You can instead accept the answer.